# Symfony query builder select by multiple joined ids (ManyToMany)

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, query-builder

Incorrect query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
    ->join('product.specifications', 'specification')
    ->andWhere("specification.id = :specificationId_1") // this
    ->andWhere("specification.id = :specificationId_2") // and this
    ->setParameter("specificationId_1", 1)
    ->setParameter("specificationId_2", 2)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Tables (`product` related to `specifications` by `ManyToMany`):

```
product:
  id  name
  1   Product1
  2   Product2
  3   Product3

specifcation:
  id   name
  1    Specification1
  2    Specification2
  3    Specification3

product_specification:
  product_id   specification_id
  1            1
  1            2
  1            3
  2            1
  2            2
  3            3
```

Expected result:
Products with ids 1 and 2.

---

What's needed:
Need to get products by ALL `specification_id` entries.

---

So, in example, I need to get products `1` and `2` by specifications `1` and `2`, because both products has this specifications.

---

`IN` operator doesn't help, because select result by specifications 1, 2 and 3 must be empty, because we don't have products which has ALL three specifications relation.

---

P.S. I understand why it's not working, but don't understand how to do it. And can't find something like in stackoverflow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("product")
    ->join("product.specifications", "specification_1")
    ->join("product.specifications", "specification_2")
    ->andWhere("specification_1.id = :specificationId_1")
    ->andWhere("specification_2.id = :specificationId_2")
    ->setParameter("specificationId_1", 1)
    ->setParameter("specificationId_2", 2)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

For each `where` need to `join` table again with new `alias`.